# Linux Version of Windows 7 Libraries

Tags: windows-7, linux, libraries

Libraries are one of the features I like about Windows 7 (admittedly, I haven't delved to deeply yet). Anyone using a similar concept on a Linux system? I figure UnionFS could work, but I've not played with that (yet).

So is anyone *doing* something like 'libraries' on Linux, what's your setup, and how do you like it?

*About Libraries*: My understanding is that they group different directories together into a single searchable/browsable 'directory'. For example, your 'music' folder could contain your music, the music in your computer's 'public' directory, and the music on a shared (Windows Vista/7) computer. As far as I know, they would be 'merged' together into a unified folder.

**Update**: The search utilities are good options; however, I'm also interested in methods that create an actual file system path, that can be used as the source in other apps (for example, group music from different locations to use in a media player). Sure symbolic links could be used, but I believe Win7 libraries show the *contents* of all directories in the 'library' directory.

Comment: The idea is very like '`tagging`' as long as the original file locations are unchanged (and file metadata retained).

Comment: I recollect a friend experimenting with python scripts on unix to get this '`tagging`' effect. This was in the early days of Google I guess.

Comment: this sounds like something doable via FUSE, but i'm not sure where to start or what might already exist...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things that I found, that seem to do what you need:

- [metatracker](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaTracker) with [trackerfs](http://code.google.com/p/trackerfs/) - seems to be the best choice
- [tagfs](http://wiki.github.com/marook/tagfs) - might be not as comfy as metatracker
- [leaftag](http://osiris.chipx86.com/svn/osiris-misc/trunk/leaftag-gnome/) - didn't find version that's new

Comment: trackerfs seems to mirror the actual 'library' directory. That seems to make metatracker a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) is a good alternative for Linux, Tim. I must say I only gained an interest in it after seeing Libraries in Windows 7. I agree with you this is indeed a great interface addition to the operating system. And they can be used for a lot more than just media files. Currently I'm already indexing and organizing projects in different programming languages, technical documentation, etc.

Gaining an interest in this, I searched for a good alternative in Linux. And Beagle does the job. Not exactly the same way. But wanna a bet it won't be long? :)

Alternatively, you can try [Meta Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/screenshots.html). I haven't tried it yet (it's on my list... for sometime) but it does offer a Windows Library type of feature through it's own Object Store.

Comment: In the process of checking those two out.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can use hard and symbolic links to create virtual directories.

Taken from [Windows-to-Linux roadmap: Part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-roadmap2.html)

> A link
>   is a reference to a file, so that you
>   can let files be seen in multiple
>   locations of the file system. However,
>   in Linux, a link can be treated as the
>   original file. As far as other
>   applications on the system are
>   concerned, a link is the original
>   file. When you make edits to a file
>   through the link, you are editing the
>   original. A link is not a copy. There
>   are two kinds of links: a hard link
>   and a symbolic link.
>
> A hard link can only reference files
>   in the same file system. It provides a
>   reference to the file's physical index
>   (also called an inode) in the file's
>   system. Hard links do not break when
>   you move the original file around
>   because they all point to the file's
>   physical data rather than its location
>   in the file structure. A hard-linked
>   file does not require the user to have
>   access rights to the original file and
>   does not show the location of the
>   original, so it has some security
>   advantages. If you delete a file that
>   has been hard linked, the file remains
>   until all references have been deleted
>   as well.
>
> A symbolic link is a pointer to a
>   file's location in the file system.
>   Symbolic links can span file systems
>   and can even point to files in a
>   remote file system. A symbolic link
>   shows the location of the original
>   file and requires a user to have
>   access rights to the original file's
>   location in order to use the link. If
>   the original file is deleted, all of
>   the symbolic links become broken. They
>   will point to a non-existent location
>   in the file system.
>
> Both types of links can be made with
>   the command ln  . By
>   default ln will make a hard link. The
>   -s switch will make a symbolic link.
>
> Create a hard link from MyFile in the current directory to /YourDir/MyFile
>   `ln MyFile /YourDir`
>
> Create a symbolic (soft) link from MyFile in
>   the current directory to /YourDir/YourFile
>   `ln -s MyFile/YourDir/Yourfile`
>
> In the above examples, MyFile,
>   /YourDir/MyFile, and /YourDir/Yourfile
>   are all treated as the same file.

Comment: I understand how symbolic links work (I used the quite frequently), what I'm looking for is someone leveraging them (or UnionFS, or something else) for functionality similar to the Windows 7 libraries - how they did it, how well it's working, etc. As mentioned in the question, symbolic links don't exactly mirror 'libraries' as I believe libraries show the *contents* of the 'linked' directories in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [UnionFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS)...

> Unionfs is a filesystem service for Linux, FreeBSD and NetBSD which
>   implements a union mount for other file systems. It allows files and
>   directories of separate file systems, known as branches, to be
>   transparently overlaid, forming a single coherent file system.
>   **Contents of directories which have the same path within the merged
>   branches will be seen together in a single merged directory**, within
>   the new, virtual filesystem.